# How do I remove exception stack traces from Serilog's console sink?

Tags: c#, serilog

Using Serilog + Serilog.Expressions, how do I make exceptions log only `Message` in the console sink and `ToString()` for file sinks? Here is my set up right now:

```cs
return new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .WriteTo.Console(GetConsoleTemplate(), _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel)
    .WriteTo.File(GetFileTemplate(), logPath.FullName)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
```

These methods configure the expression template I use. There's a "common" part of the template, which gets specialized depending on the type of sink (console or file).

```cs
private static string GetBaseTemplateString()
{
    var scope = LogProperty.Scope;

    return
        $"{{#if {scope} is not null}}{{{scope}}}: {{#end}}" +
        "{@m}\n" +
        "{@x}";
}

private static ExpressionTemplate GetConsoleTemplate()
{
    var template = "[{@l:u3}] " + GetBaseTemplateString();
    return new ExpressionTemplate(template, theme: TemplateTheme.Code);
}

private static ExpressionTemplate GetFileTemplate()
{
    var template = "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3}] " + GetBaseTemplateString();
    return new ExpressionTemplate(template);
}
```

Right now, `{@x}` seems to result in `exception.ToString()` but what I really want is `exception.Message` for just the console sink. So far I haven't found a way to do this. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70028037/157971), which suggests there is a way to do this using Serilog.Expressions, but the solution provided there doesn't work. The template seems to be wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [`Serilog.Exceptions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Exceptions) NuGet package to your project.

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
```

Include a call to `.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()` in your logger configuration.

```
var log =  new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .WriteTo.Console(GetConsoleTemplate())
    .WriteTo.File(GetFileTemplate(), logPath.FullName)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails() // << Newly added.
    .CreateLogger();
```

Use below marker (instead of `{@x}`) in the template where you only want the exception message.
The `Message` specifier is the name of the property you want to appear in the logger output.

```
{ExceptionDetail['Message']}
```

In the template where you want the full `ToString()` representation of the exception you can keep using `{@x}`.